# Find max salary and name of employee, if multiple records than print all

Tags: mysql

I want to print name and salary amount of the employee which has highest salary, till now its okay but if there are multiple records than print all. There are two table given :-

EMPLOYEE TABLE :-

[image]

SALARY TABLE:-
[image: salary table]

my query is: -

```sql
SELECT E.NAME, S.AMOUNT 
FROM `salary` S, 
     employee E 
WHERE S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.ID 
  and S.AMOUNT = (SELECT max(`AMOUNT`) 
                  FROM `salary`)
```

is there any better way to find out the solution ?

Comment: Do not use old-style comma join, use explicit JOIN syntax. Move subquery from WHERE to FROM. If MySQL version is 8+ - then rewrite completely and use RANK() in CTE.

Comment: Better? IN what way? and consider changing from comma joins to explicit join.

Answer (score 1):

It is "with ties" functionality what you're trying to achieve. Unfortunately mySQL doesn't support that (in the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) there is nothing to add to the "LIMIT" part of the query), so you have no other option rather than looking for max salary first and filter records afterwards.

So, your solution is fine for that case.

Alternatively, if you're on version 8 and newer, you may move the subquery to the with clause

```
with max_sal as (
  select max(amount) ms from salary
)

SELECT E.NAME, S.AMOUNT 
FROM salary S
JOIN employee E
  ON S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.ID
JOIN max_sal ms
  ON S.AMOUNT = ms.ms
```

or search for it in the join directly

```
SELECT E.NAME, S.AMOUNT 
  FROM salary S
  JOIN employee E
    ON S.EMPLOYEE_ID = E.ID
  JOIN (select max(amount) ms from salary) ms
    ON S.AMOUNT = ms.ms
```

But I'm sure it won't get you any better performance

Comment: thank you. this is the best solution with proper explanation

Comment: @Ravindra no problem. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

I like solving them with a join:

```
WITH M as (select max(amount) as amount from salary)
   SELECT E.NAME, S.AMOUNT 
   FROM M JOIN SALARY USING(AMOUNT) JOIN Employee USING(Id)
```

but your solution is perfectly fine..